# How to use function that can calculate the sum squard

Tags: python, pandas

I have created the following function to calculate the sum squared

```
def sum_of_squares(n):
    sm = 0
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        sm = sm + (i * i)

    return sm
```

this is a snap from the header of the df2

```
| ACCX     |  ACCY   | ACCZ    |
| -------- | ------- |---------|
| 1.224976 | 0.137329| 0.576782|
| 0.071411 | 0.576782| 1.417236|
| 0.005493 | 0.258179| 1.517078|
```

```
a_energy = df2.rolling(170, step=170).apply(sum_of_squares)
```

```
but it got the following error
raise DataError("No numeric types to aggregate")
pandas.errors.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

Comment: Do you want to apply the function rowwise or colwise?

Comment: rowwise for each 170 row

Answer (score 0):

When you use apply, the function will receive the whole series. But your function seems to work with 'n' not sure what is `n` here?

IIUC what you are looking for is:

```
df.rolling(170, step=170).apply(lambda x: (x**2).sum())
```